# Pass by reference OR by value

Tags: php

I need to be able to allow in the constructor of a class to pass by reference OR by value.

```
class test{

   public function __construct(&$value){
   }

}

$reference = "I'll be passed by reference of course";

//Everything good
$test = new Test($reference);

//This of course WONT work
$test = new Test("This would be by value ... on a reference, not cool since I don't refere to any other variable");
```

Any thoughts? Thanks :)

Comment: Rethink your design would be my advice, this smells like practices which will hinder you later on. Or ignore the error, those are your 2 options :)

Comment: I'd never ignore the error :|

Comment: don't do this. "I want to order some steak, but just in case I decide to convert to veganism, I'd like to pretend the steak is a potato"

Comment: No, not really it's not what I'm trying to do :/
PS: I love meat

Comment: What exactly is the point of this design to begin with? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? A parameter passed by reference is typically an "output parameter". It makes no sense to pass a value into it, if it's designed for output.

Comment: I thought it was really clear? If I pass a string literal I want it to be passed by value and if I pass a variable I'd like it to be a reference ?

Comment: *Why* do you want it to be a reference? If you accept a parameter by reference, that means you're intending to modify the variable in a way that the change will be propagated into the scope of the caller as well. If you're not going to do that, there's no point in accepting by reference. *If* you're going to do that, then what's the point of allowing the API to be used in some other "mode" where that doesn't happen?

Comment: Perhaps because the string literal could be too big? Yeah that reason comes to mind.

Comment: How does the length of the string affect your decision to edit it? What bearing does the decision to pass as a variable or string literal have on the size of the data?

Comment: Memory??????????? Performance??????????????

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps because the string literal could be too big?

If you're doing this for the purpose of optimisation, then it's entirely unnecessary. The string will *not* be copied when you pass it into the function! Passing it by reference does not use less memory or is otherwise more efficient. PHP's handling of memory is beyond your control, and PHP is handling things for you and doesn't need such optimisations from your side. See [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), which is what PHP does behind the scenes.

PHP references are not C pointers! They're a higher level concept for the purpose of "output parameters", not for optimisations. Your API is obviously not designed to use references, so don't use them.

Comment: Ok, could you be kind enough to explain why does this happens then?

http://runnable.com/VBNI78ZMIr5MFB_E/test-reference-for-php

Comment: Passing an array is a different topic, since it *is* copying the array structure, even if it's not copying the *values* contained within it. You seem to have found just the right number where the array overhead pushes it over the edge. A more useful test though is this: http://3v4l.org/6U7Os

Comment: Got it, so in the case of arrays is pretty much correct to pass by reference, however in the case of strings, I shouldn't really bother since string interning takes effect.
However, if I would change the string somehow inside the function that would be a new zval, and in that case it would  duplicate memory (thanks to COW). Correct?

Comment: Please see this example in which I basically break the internal reference inside the hash table by adding another string, in this case I understand the zval changes hence, COW gains effect.

http://runnable.com/VBONts3t1e40fLVW/breaking-internal-reference-for-php

Comment: Yes, whenever you modify a string, it creates a new string, and there will be at least a brief window in which both the old and the new string need to exist in memory at once, until the old one gets garbage collected. (The exception being `$str[42] = 'f'`, e.g. direct byte offset manipulation, I think.) It doesn't really matter whether the string was passed by reference or not here.